# Indirect injection proofs

Tags: set-theory

I am interested in (indirectly) proving the existence of injection between two infinite sets. We have three infinite sets $A$ ,$B$ , and $C$. We have injective function $f: A \to B$ and injective function $g: A \to C$.

> Under which conditions do injections $f$ and $g$ imply the existence of an injection $h: B \to C$?

Also, Under which conditions do injections $f$ and $g$ imply the existence of an injection $h: B \to C$ and an injection $k: C \to B$?

Comment: That f or g is surjective.

Answer (score 4):

If the only information you have is

- $A,B,C$ are sets.

  There exists an injection $f: A \to B$.

  There exists an injection $g: A \to C$.

then all that says is that $|A| \le |B|$ and $|A| \le |C|$.

For any sets $B,C$, either $|B| \le |C|$ or  $|C| \le |B|$ (or both), but with the given information, you can't decide which one, hence you don't know whether ot not there is an injection $h: B \to C$.

However, if it's given that $f$ is not only injective but also surjective (and hence bijective), then $|A| = |B|$. Then since $|A| \le |C|$, we get $|B| \le |C|$, hence there is an injection $h: B \to C$.

Along the same lines, if it's given that $f$ and $g$ are *both* bijective, then $|A| = |B|$ and $|A| = |C|$, hence $|B| = |C|$, so there is a bijection from $B$ to $C$, which implies the existence of injections $h,k$ which you asked for.

Comment: I think "under which conditions . . ." means "what ***additional*** information suffices to imply . . ." From the OP's use of the phrase "under which conditions" I would surmise that he knows that the given information is insufficient.

Comment: Yes. I am looking for additional information (conditions).

Comment: Ok, I edited my answer to address the issue of additional conditions.

Comment: While your post qualifies as an answer. It does not cover interesting cases (for  me). The interesting cases for me occur when one of the functions $f$ and $g$ is strictly injective ($|A|< |B|$ or $|A| < |C|$).

Comment: The existence of injective and/or surjective functions between two sets depends solely on the comparison of their cardinalities. Thus, if $f,g$ are strictly injective, there's nothing $f,g$ can tell you about the comparison of the cardinalities of the sets $B,C$.